# How to tackle/fix SimpleFSLock in Lucene

Tags: c#-4.0, lucene.net

I get this error when i do update or add the lucene documnet. I know this happens  when indexwriter is being used by other resource we get this SimpleFSLock Excetion , but in my scenario i always close my IndexWriter so there is no chance of indexwriter being opened.

**Is there a way if i get this exception i can fix this.**

**Edit :**

```
static object myLock = new object(); 

  public static void AddDocument(//some params)
        {
            lock (myLock)
            {
                try
                {
//I get the exception thrown on below line [not sure but might be file have been locked due to other resource accessing it : how can i free this lock]
                    IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(GetFileInfo(indexName), analyzer, false);
                    writer.AddDocument(*//some document //*);
                    writer.Optimize();
                    writer.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    log.LogWarn(null, ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Post the chunk of code where you are performing the locking..

Answer (score 0):

*"but in my scenario i always close my IndexWriter so there is no chance of indexwriter being opened"*
I wouldn't be so sure!

Answer (score 0):

You dont handles exceptions in your code, you should have a finaly clause that closes() the IndexWriter when an exception occurs to clear the "write.lock" file.

Add that to your code, and then go to your index directory and manually delete the write.lock file.